# barman + postgresql not start after barman retore

Tags: linux, backup, postgresql, backup-restoration

I use the barman ( http://www.pgbarman.org/ ) , for backup and restore on my linux redhat machine

after restore , we start the postgresql as the following

```
 systemctl start postgresql.service
```

but postgresql not startup

from the log:

```
  /var/lib/pgsql/backups/data/pg_log
```

we seen the following errors

```
 requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point
```

please advice what is the meaning of this FATAL error?

```
 more pg_log


 LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-08-06 07:30:49 UTC
 LOG:  restored log file "00000008.history" from archive
 LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2017-08-06 07:30:49.813508+00
 LOG:  restored log file "0000000800000000000000C1" from archive
 LOG:  redo starts at 0/C1000080
 LOG:  recovery stopping before commit of transaction 96139, time 2017-08-06 07:30:49.855629+00
 LOG:  redo done at 0/C1001B90
 FATAL:  requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point
 LOG:  startup process (PID 55858) exited with exit code 1
 LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

example - when I start the postgres service:

```
  systemctl start postgresql.service
  Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with 
  error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
  for details.


  ls
  backup_label.old     pg_hba.conf                   pg_hba.conf.2017-08-
  03_13:08  pg_snapshots  pg_xlog                           
  postgresql.conf.2017-08-03_13:03
  barman_xlog          pg_hba.conf.2017-08-03_12:07  pg_ident.conf                 
  pg_stat_tmp   postgresql.conf                   postgresql.conf.2017-08-
  03_13:08
  base                 pg_hba.conf.2017-08-03_12:22  pg_log                        
  pg_subtrans   postgresql.conf.2017-08-03_12:07  postgresql.conf.origin
  global               pg_hba.conf.2017-08-03_12:24  pg_multixact                  
  pg_tblspc     postgresql.conf.2017-08-03_12:22  postmaster.opts
  pg_clog              pg_hba.conf.2017-08-03_12:28  pg_notify                     
  pg_twophase   postgresql.conf.2017-08-03_12:24  recovery.done
  pg_hba_bak.conf.old  pg_hba.conf.2017-08-03_13:03  pg_serial                     
  PG_VERSION    postgresql.conf.2017-08-03_12:28
```

Comment: You still have the recovery file in the pg data.

Comment: sorry - what you mean about that I still have this file?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the timing of the error. Does the restore finish correctly or...? That error sounds like you are trying to do Point In Time Recovery with an older point than the base backup...

Comment: Try removing recovery.conf from the pg data folder.

Comment: @Florin I remove the file and start the postgres , and postgres service was start successfully , so I just asking if by remove this  file ( recover.conf ) is ok and not damage the DB ?

Comment: That file is only required for the Point in Time Restore procedure. When that file is present, the DB will start in recovery mode, not in normal operation mode.

Comment: Do not just remove `recovery.conf`. For some reason you have  recovery target that's too soon after crash recovery / snapshot. What is the exact restore command you used? What's the content of the generated `recovery.conf`? This *should not* happen and it's not necessarily safe to use this database, there could be corruption due to an incomplete restore.

Comment: I use this syntax from barman for restore -  barman recover --target-time "$BEGIN_TIME"  --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@$IP"   main-db-server   $ID  /var/lib/pgsql/data

Comment: @shalom You cannot recover to the time you start the backup, so there's your problem. If you want the soonest possible recovery point you can use recovery target 'immediate'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to remove the `recover.conf` file after restoring.

This file is only required for PiTR and not for normal DB operation. The solution is to simply remove it.

Comment: in other case , after I removed the recovery.conf , still postgres not start , see my update question in the last , do you think I missed something ?

Comment: No, that's not it. This error indicates that a recovery target has been set that's too old for this backup.

Comment: @CraigRinger, I couldn't agree more. But I think that the problem is actually because the transaction logs were already rolled and the OP didn't remove the file. Since the transaction logs were already rolled, of course, the transactions in the DB are newer than the recovery point specified in the recovery file.